# H710p can't see physical disks

Tags: dell

I'm trying to add a Dell h710p controller to a Dell T5600.  I have the card in slot 1 and I have disabled the onboard controller.
First I tried adding Crucial MX500 500GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5 Inch Internal SSD drives but inside the PERC h710p configuration utility no physical drives could be seen or added.
I assumed the drive may not be compatible so I bought Samsung 860 EVO v-nand ssd drives and the controller cannot see those either.
I updated the computer bios as well as the h710p bios but no luck.
Are both types of drives not supported?
What SSDs can I use that I know will work with the h710p and t5600?

Comment: You have moved the SAS cable over to the H710P, haven't you?

Answer (score 3):

PERC H710p cards are not limited to certified drives only; rather, they will recognize any working, connected disk. So if your controller does not see any disk, you probably have an hardware issue either on the backplane or on the PERC card itself.